# interaction failed - discord.py sports alert cog

Tags: python, discord.py

My brother and I are trying to make our discord bot easier to use, from typing commands to moving to interactive buttons and menus for my father and his friends to use directly from their smartphones. So in this sense we're trying to create a cog module to set alerts across different sports and we always get "This interaction failed" even if pycharm doesn't return anything out of the ordinary or any error output at all when we try the alert command:

After typing the command and clicking any option it doesn't continue in the alert setup and just gives this error:
[This interaction failed][1]
Before posting this question, we checked and found that most of the info online is old and regards a "discord-components" feature (or other forks and libraries) that I've read is deprecated and that now, this is how its supposed to be done, via import discord.ui.
After a week or so of frustration and google searching, we tried reading up on some info we found on github:
https://gist.github.com/lykn/a2b68cb790d6dad8ecff75b2aa450f23
Browsed through youtube and here on SO but haven't understood where exactly we're failing since neither me nor my brother work in IT...What are we missing???

Comment: There is no event called `on_select` as far as I know. Just set the [`callback`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=select#discord.ui.Select.callback) for the select menu instead.

Comment: thank you for your reply @3nws and sorry, but could you bear with me? where and what exactly do I need to set?

Comment: After you create the `select` object, you set its `callback` attribute to the function you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is no event called `on_select`. `discord-components` has been archived and cannot be used with newer versions. To get the callback of your select menu, it is best to use a `discord.ui.View` class.

```
async def show_alert_options(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send("Select an alert:", view=AlertMenu())

class AlertMenu(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @discord.ui.select(
        placeholder="Please select an option", 
        custom_id="alert_menu",
        options=[
        discord.SelectOption(label="NFL", value="footbal"),
        discord.SelectOption(label="NBA", value="basketball")
    ])
    async def select_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, select: discord.ui.Select):
        ...
```

And presumably the same for other select menus, read more in [discord.Interaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.Interaction), [discord.ui.View](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.View), [discord.ui.Select](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.Select)